# WARNING: Third-party TestEngine implementations are forbidden to use the reserved 'junit-' prefix for their ID: 'junit-platform-suite'

Tags: java, maven, junit

Tryin to run my tests on Java8 jdk 1.8:

```
WARNING: Third-party TestEngine implementations are forbidden to use the reserved 'junit-' prefix for their ID: 'junit-platform-suite'
```

my `POM`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>

        <cucumber.version>7.3.3</cucumber.version>
        <selenium.version>4.1.4</selenium.version>
        <awaitility.version>4.2.0</awaitility.version>
        <assertj.version>3.22.0</assertj.version>
        <commonsmodel.version>5.3.3</commonsmodel.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M6</maven.surefire.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.12.0</commons-lang3.version>
        <junit-jupiter-engine.version>5.8.2</junit-jupiter-engine.version>
        <maven-cucumber-reporting.version>5.7.0</maven-cucumber-reporting.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.jodah</groupId>
            <artifactId>failsafe</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>${awaitility.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-cucumber-reporting.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>TestExecutor</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                                <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <includes>**/ExecutorTest.java</includes>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <!--cucumber report plugin-->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-cucumber-reporting.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>generate-cucumber-reports</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <projectName>Automation report</projectName>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                                    <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</inputDirectory>
                                    <jsonFiles>
                                        <param>**/*.json</param>
                                    </jsonFiles>
                                    <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


</project>
```

full error code:

```
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
Jun 14, 2022 2:23:06 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher validateEngineIds
WARNING: Third-party TestEngine implementations are forbidden to use the reserved 'junit-' prefix for their ID: 'junit-platform-suite'
Jun 14, 2022 2:23:06 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-platform-suite' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.enableImplicitConfigurationParameters(Z)Lorg/junit/platform/launcher/core/LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder;
    at org.junit.platform.suite.commons.SuiteLauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.enableImplicitConfigurationParameters(SuiteLauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.java:121)
    at org.junit.platform.suite.engine.SuiteTestDescriptor.discover(SuiteTestDescriptor.java:100)
    at org.junit.platform.suite.engine.DiscoverySelectorResolver$$Lambda$169/8350604.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.suite.engine.DiscoverySelectorResolver.discoverSuites(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:36)
    at org.junit.platform.suite.engine.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:42)
    at org.junit.platform.suite.engine.SuiteTestEngine.discover(SuiteTestEngine.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:168)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.discover(LazyLauncher.java:48)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.TestPlanScannerFilter.accept(TestPlanScannerFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.api.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.scanClasspath(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:456)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:595)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:581)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate (generate-cucumber-reports) @ testing ---
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class org.jfrog.hudson.maven2.MavenDependenciesRecorder$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.609 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-14T14:23:07+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/191M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate (generate-cucumber-reports) on project testing: Execution generate-cucumber-reports of goal net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate: org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/appl/xxx/maven/repo/net/masterthought/maven-cucumber-reporting/5.7.0/maven-cucumber-reporting-5.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/appl/xxx/maven/repo/net/masterthought/cucumber-reporting/5.7.0/cucumber-reporting-5.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/appl/xxx/maven/repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[JENKINS] Archiving /appl/xxx/jenkins/workspace/Customer_Portal/web-full-suite/pom.xml to com.xxx/testing/1.0-SNAPSHOT/testing-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
channel stopped
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level /cucumber/cucumber.html to /appl/xxx/jenkins/jobs/Customer_Portal/jobs/web-full-suite/htmlreports/HTML_20Report
ERROR: Specified HTML directory '/cucumber/cucumber.html' does not exist.
Publishing Selenium report...
Copying the reports.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got a dependency convergence problem. Though I couldn't tell you where.

What you can do to alleviate this is to use a bill of materials for both JUnit and Cucumber and then use all JUnit and Cucumber dependencies without further versions.

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Additionally these two don't look needed:

```xml
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
        </dependency>
```

```xml
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                                <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
```

For Cucumber you can find a minimal example of what you'd need in the [cucumber-java-skeleton](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton).

Comment: thanks for having a look, I removed the two that don't look needed (cant remember why I added these in the first place) and it looks like it's working locally just fine now! Thanks!

What was your thinking behind this?

Comment: if you could be so kind to check my other question (the error I still get now: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate (generate-cucumber-reports) on project testing: Execution generate-cucumber-reports of goal net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate: org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils`)

Comment: My thinking was 1) that your POM was a bit messy, that usually indicates the dependency tree is not well understood, and 2) typically `NoSuchMethodError` indicates a problem with mismatched dependency versions and 3) and I wrote the `junit-platform-suite` engine so I knew there was a possibility of mismatched dependencies because of the warning.

Comment: Your `maven-cucumber-reporting` is declared as a dependency rather then a plugin. That probably explain it. To understand better what is happening you may want to start with a clean pom then gradually build up again.

Comment: is that an answer for my second error above (the arrayUtils) one? I have the `maven-cucumber-reporting` as well as a dependency as a plugin indeed. Should I delete the first?

Comment: I missed the second one. And I don't know if removing it from the dependencies will fix it. However in general, removing everything not needed makes the problem easier to solve.